# MySQL: Query for list of available options for SET

Tags: mysql

In particular table there exists a field of `SET` type with specific legal values:

```
    personType SET('CUSTOMER','SUPPLIER','EMPLOYEE', 'CONTRACTOR') NOT NULL
```

Is there any way to query MySQL to get a list of the valid values? In the MySQL interpreter I would just run `DESCRIBE someTable;` however if there is a more direct method that one could use programmatically without lots of parsing it would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems not... according to the MySQL manual: "To determine all possible values for a SET column, use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl_name LIKE set_col` and parse the SET definition in the Type column of the output." - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

Comment: If you have this requirement, you may wish to consider moving away from using SET, and consider using a "lookup table".

Comment: @J.Bruni: Thanks, if it is so mentioned in the fine manual then I see that my efforts are futile! Can you please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it if another all-SQL workaround isn't posted? Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Thanks, refactoring was my first inclination but this is a rather well-entrenched application and that is not practical at this stage.

Comment: Have you considered adding another table that has all the values and using that? Since adding values requires a schema change to add records to the set, you can just as easily add records to the table at the same time.

It wouldn't require a change to the application to add values.

If you still need help, please spell out your requirements and restrictions.

Comment: Thanks, Marcus. What you are suggesting would break data integrity principals (or is that meta-data integrity). I am unfamiliar with triggers but a trigger might be able to propagate the change (or better yet a stored procedure to make the change). However, it is really not that big a deal. There are quite a few ways to attack the issue, but I wanted to see if there was a direct (SQL) way to do it. The values hardy ever change (in practice, they should never change). I could even hard code it.

Comment: @dotancohen: please let me know if you prefer my new answer below, or if you still want to accept the comment above (so I'll make it an answer)... BTW, it's my first time answering twice the same question... it will be fun to post a third answer :)

Comment: @J.Bruni: I cannot believe that query! I edited it to add `DISTINCT` to two of the inner queries, but I don't have edit privileges so you might want to add them. Thank you, that is quite an amazing query!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now, this simply freaks out, but it is MySQL-only and it works!

```
SELECT TRIM("'" FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   (SELECT TRIM(')' FROM SUBSTR(column_type, 5)) FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'some_table' AND column_name = 'some_column'),
',', @r:=@r+1), ',', -1)) AS item
FROM (SELECT @r:=0) deriv1,
(SELECT ID FROM information_schema.COLLATIONS) deriv2
HAVING @r <= 
   (SELECT LENGTH(column_type) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column_type, ',', ''))
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'some_table' AND column_name = 'some_column');
```

Just replace "some_table" and "some_column" for your specific table/column, and see the magic!

You will see a weird usage of "information_schema.COLLATIONS" - this is because we need a table there - *any table* - containing **at least N rows**, where N is the number of elements in your set.

Comment: Please, don't ask me to explain what is going on there! :-)

Comment: This answer was based on comment "Posted by Alex V on September 7 2008 5:20am" at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Amazing! I had to add `DISTINCT` to the first and last inner queries as they were returning multiple identical results. But then it worked and I literally laughed out loud and the wife asked what's funny. Thank you, that is quite some effort that you put into that thing!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    column_type
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_name = 'some_table'
AND
    column_name = 'some_column';
```

Returns:

```
column_type
------------------
set('this','that')
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be what OP asked for. `DESCRIBE someTable;` is even simpler than this...

Comment: @J.Bruni he wants to `DESCRIBE` programmatically, don't know in which language so I gave an SQL.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not quite what I am looking for. Although this query does return a response that can then be parsed to get the info, it does not return a response that could be used directly. You are right that I am looking for a pure SQL answer. I do know how to parse with the languages that I usually use MySQL with if it comes to that, though!

Comment: you might call a stored procedure to split the output column: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/199128

Comment: @vulkanino: That is quite elaborate! I'd rather not implement a state machine for the generic case of escaped values in the `SET` field, but for known-simple fields that is a decent solution. Thanks!

Comment: yes, but you did not specify a programming language, and that procedure does the trick with SQL. with any language it would be super-easy to parse a string like `set('this','that')` and extract the field names.

Answer (score 1):

The function below returns an array containing all available options for SET with some parsing but not "lots of parsing"... :)

```
function get_set_values($table_name, $field_name)
{
    $sql = 'DESCRIBE ' . $table_name . ' ' . $field_name;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return str_getcsv( trim( substr( $row['Type'], 3 ), '()' ), ',', "'" );
}
```

Remember that in a set column you may have a combination of values or even an empty value (these are also valid).

Comment: Thank you, but this is exactly what I mentioned in the OP as being what I don't want! I'm actually not using PHP right now, though I am proficient in that language. +1 for that terrific last line though!