# How to use the count function to get data from another table and make a column with the return value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a new column in my table (genre_stats) where the value in it comes from counting how many occurrences of a certain genre occurs from another table (movies).

Table 1 (movies):
has a column called "genre" with values like "Drama" or "Romance,Horror,Drama"

Table 2 (genre_Stats):
has a primary key column called "genre" where only one genre is listed in each row

I want to create another column in table 2 to count how many times each genre has occurred in table 1.

Comment: Why would you create a table?  Table 2 sounds like it should be a view whose values would be generated when called.  Or it could be materialized to be generated at a specific interval.  Are you concerned about performance?  How Big do you expect "Movies" to get?  Do you have index on "genre"? in table 1?  Or a view joining table 2 and 1 which gets you the count...

Comment: yes it's mainly for performance, the data is static for now, so i just want to do the calculations once and be bale to pull them out again without running the function all again. movies is a little over 86k rows and 13 columns, I'm not sure what you mean by index on genre, the genre data value is SET with only 27 items. i don't have a view joining table 2 and 1..

Comment: Ok.  We need to see the definition of genre_stats is there more than just this count column and the genre?  and does table 1 really have multiple values of in the "Genre" field which violates 3rd normal form?

Comment: yes genre_stats only has two columns, genre and genre_count, and the column "genre" in table 1 has a type of SET which sometimes has rows with multiple genres(no duplication within the row obviously), is there an easy way to share the tables here?

Comment: ug.. set and counting is ugly I need to look up how to do that in mySQL again.  I now understand your difficulty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620904/how-to-count-unique-set-values-in-mysql: not pretty which is why normalizing the data is a better option if not too late.  One table field should not have multiple values..  I know it's a feature; it's just not a great one in a RDBMS design.  a "MovieGenere" table should exist listing all the genere's for a movie.

Comment: if it's that much of a problem i can easily switch the SET type to VARCHAR or something else, i just thought it's more efficient/elegant to have it as SET, but thanks anyways for your help, i will look into that link

Comment: it's more of a cardinality issue.  you should't have multiple values in one column.  once that's resolved; a count and group by can be used easily to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

As @xQbert mentioned in the comments above, I agree it should be a view/MV but still if you want a separate table, below is the insert query:

```
INSERT INTO GENRE_STATS(GENRE,GENRE_COUNT)
SELECT GENRE, COUNT(*) FROM MOVIES GROUP BY GENRE;
```

Also, if there is a new entry in movies table for a particular genre, you'll see the latest count in view whereas in case of table, it will be the old one.

Comment: first had to make the column "Genre_count" for this query to run, but then i ran into another error "1062 duplicate entry 'romance' for key 'genre_stats.Primary', not sure why it would give such an error if it's not modifying the primary key column?

Comment: Can you please share the structure of the table that you created?